# get requests fail when cache manifest is applied

Tags: ajax, https, coldfusion, html5-appcache

I'm comfortable working with $.ajax and also in using cache.manifest. Recently I decided to start using "get" instead of "post" to help see the parameters easier.

In this proof-of-concept, if I delete the cache.manifest from the server, everything works. But when I put the cache.manifest on the server, the page stops working with an undefined jqXHR.responseText.

Furthermore, if I change the get to a post, it works with the cache.manifest.

Q: Does an https require a post, making "get" invalid if you are using a cache manifest? It seems to be working if the cache manifest is missing and it works with the cache manifest if I use post.

```js
var local = {}

local.type = 'get'
local.dataType = 'text'
local.data = {}
local.data.CtrlName = 'testing123'
var promise = $.ajax('where_ctrlName.cfm',local)
promise.done(done)
promise.fail(fail)
function done(response) {
 console.log(response)
}
function fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 debugger
}

window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', updateReady, false)

function updateReady() {
 if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
  $('body').html('<h1>Updating</h1>')
  setTimeout(reloadCache,1000)
 }
}
function reloadCache() {
 window.location.reload()
}
```

```html
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my cache.manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
```

For What It's Worth, this is an https call.

Comment: I think my conclusion is: I have to use post with cache manifest.

Comment: POST works with cache manifest. Your Comment helped !